# Not sure how to port a C# encryption function to PHP

Tags: c#, php, encryption, hash

I have a basic encryption function in C# that I use to encrypt and store save files for a game, which uses a user's username and password for the game's website. Recently I realized that if a user was to change their password, it would cause their save to become inaccessible, since it's encrypted with their old password. So, I'm trying to build a PHP function to "reconvert" their save when they update their password. Unfortunately, the problem comes in that C# uses byte arrays to perform hashing, and PHP uses strings, and I'm not sure how to reconcile the two. Here's the general process:

- hash username (into byte array)
- hash password (into byte array)
- concatenate username + password hashes (into twice-as-long byte array)
- hash result to get key (which is back to the 256-bit length)
- xor file byte-by-byte with key to get encrypted file

I'm not sure how to accomplish this in PHP. I was originally trying to use `unpack('C*', hash("sha256", $thing_to_be_hashed, false))` but this didn't seem to yield the correct byte arrays. Then I tried this:

```
$new_key = hash("sha256", hash("sha256", $username, false) . hash("sha256", $newpass, false), false);
$old_key = hash("sha256", hash("sha256", $username, false) . hash("sha256", $oldpass, false), false);

$conversion_key = array();
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($new_key); ++$i) {
    $conversion_key[] = $old_key[$i] ^ $new_key[$i]; 
    // this part with the array is a bit wonky, I know, but it didn't seem like
    // it would have worked anyway since I was xor'ing things like 'f' and '3'
    // instead of bytes like '23' and '57'.
}
$file_contents = file_get_contents("savefile.sav");
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($file_contents); ++$i) {
    $file_contents[$i] = $file_contents[$i] ^ $conversion_key[$i % count($conversion_key)]; // I read somewhere I can access $file_contents like this to get bytes
}
```

Neither method works, unfortunately, at any stage (the previous unpack method didn't produce correct byte arrays for even the first stage of hashing, nor am I sure I was putting them back into a string correctly for the second stage). Would appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

EDIT: It occurred to me `unpack()` wouldn't be giving me the correct byte arrays because it's literally decoding the strings; so I guess my main question is firstly "how would I convert the hexits returned by `hash()` to byte arrays?" and secondly "how would I go about hashing those byte arrays?" (with corollary "would converting the byte arrays back to strings of hexits and hashing those be sufficient?")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contrast to .NET where strings are encoded Unicode sequences, PHP's strings are dumb sequences of bytes -- so in essence, they already *are* byte arrays. So on the PHP side you can do all you need with strings and there is no need to involve arrays at all, which in turn means `unpack` is not required.

The main thing to deal with is that PHP hash functions return hex-encoded instead of straight binary output by default. It's very easy to convert from one to the other: use [`hex2bin`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php), but it's also much easier to just give the third (optional) argument as `true`.

So you can get the hashes you need with:

```
// for convenience
function sha256($data) {
    return hash("sha256", $data, true);
}

$new_key = sha256(sha256($username).sha256($newpass));
$old_key = sha256(sha256($username).sha256($oldpass));
```

This function will then XOR the two keys:

```
function str_xor($str1, $str2) {
    if (strlen($str1) != strlen($str2)) {
        return false;
    }

    $len = strlen($str1);
    for($i=0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $str1[$i] = $str1[$i] ^ $str2[$i];
    }

    return $str1;
}
```

So you can then use your existing loop to "re-encrypt" the saved data from one key to the other.

Comment: So, essentially, I should wrap all my outputs of `hash` with `hex2bin` before doing anything with them? Then, can I access each byte with `$string_that_is_secretly_just_bytes[$i]`?

Comment: @AlexVanLiew: Not needed, there's the third argument on `hash` that does this automatically. Yes, you can treat strings as arrays directly. I 'm still adding to the answer.

Comment: I was under the impression that argument returned strings like "1000100100000100", that's nice to know. I think this will work, let me check.

Comment: It did indeed work. It took me way too long to check because I had a number of errors with both loading the file and misreading my hashing process (twice). Thanks for your help.